# How to use awx cli?

Tags: docker, ssl, ansible, command-line-interface, ansible-awx

Installed awx by docker-compose from [official guide](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/INSTALL.md#docker-compose).

Installed awx cli this way:

```
pip install "https://github.com/ansible/awx/archive/11.1.0.tar.gz#egg=awxkit&subdirectory=awxkit"
```

Check its configuration

```
# awx config
{
     "base_url": "https://127.0.0.1:443",
     "token": "",
     "use_sessions": false,
     "credentials": {
          "default": {
               "username": "admin",
               "password": "password"
          }
     }
}
```

Get user list

```
# awx --conf.host https://127.0.0.1:443 \
>     --conf.username admin --conf.password password \
>     --conf.insecure \
>     users list

...

There was a network error of some kind trying to reach https://127.0.0.1:443.
You might need to specify (or double-check) --conf.host

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/ (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))
```

It was installed by default configuration without SSL. How to change the `base_url`?

I checked the [Authentication document](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towercli/authentication.html#authentication), can't pass auth due to the https issue.

---

From the document, this way can generate document:

```
# pip install sphinx sphinxcontrib-autoprogram

~ TOWER_HOST=https://awx.example.org TOWER_USERNAME=example TOWER_PASSWORD=secret make clean html
~ cd build/html/ && python -m http.server
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ..
```

But when I ran it got this error

```
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
```

Where to run this command?

Comment: It clearly says `ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.'`, so add `env NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1 awx` to your command or `export NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1` in your environment to tell it that you don't need a proxy for localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one worked on my system:

awx --conf.host http://127.0.0.1:80

It lists all available options without any errors